# Calculation mean across dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, average, mean

Beginners MATLAB question 
I have 4 variables(beam1,beam2,beam3,beam4) in separate arrays with the same dimensions (23746 x 35). I want to calculate the average of the 4 arrays to have an answer in one array with the same size (23746 x 35). In other words I want to average the values in the first dimension.

x = beam1,beam2,beam3,beam4
xx = mean(x,1)

Gives a 1x35 array and

x = beam1,beam2,beam3,beam4
xx = mean(x,2)

Gives a 23746x1 array

How do I keep the same dimensions (23746 x 35) in the new array and compute the average value of the 4 individual arrays?

Many thanks

Comment: could you post the full code, including the beam arrays ?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't simply doing

`xx = (beam1 + beam2 + beam3 + beam4)/4`

give what you want?

Note that it's typically bad practice to have variable names that only differ by an appended integer such as you have.  You've be better creating the data as a 3-dimenional array where

```
beam_data = beam1;
beam_data(:,:,2) = beam2;
beam_data(:,:,3) = beam3;
beam_data(:,:,4) = beam4;
```

In this way if you have more (or less) beams then you don't have a proliferation of variables.

It also means irrespective of how many beams you have the mean would be calculates along the 3rd dimension

```
beam_mean = mean(beam_data,3);
```

Comment: Thanks Phil and yes, your first solution seems obvious now! I'm learning as I go and the second part makes sense too.

Comment: @lisse welcome to SO. Please, if the answer Phil provided solves your problem, mark it as the accepted answer (click the tick beside it), so that your issue appears resolved on the board.